# Cannot find view for MyProjectName.Views.MyViewName

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have two folders **ViewModels** and **Views**.In ViewModels I have two classes: ShellViewModel and AViewModel, in View I have two forms ShellView and AView.
ShellView has a button, when I click it, AView is opened and there is an error:

> Cannot find view for DBStudent.Views.Aview.

In my Bootstrapper class I change:
from this:

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
}
```

to this:

```
   protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)  
   {            
        DisplayRootViewFor<AViewModel>();
   }
```

And Aview is opened and there no error

Why does this happen?

I opened AView like this:

```
IWindowManager manager = new WindowManager();
public void CreateClick()
{               
    manager.ShowDialog(new AView());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass an instance of the view model to the window manager:

```
public void CreateClick()
{
    manager.ShowDialog(new AViewModel());
}
```

A view model should not create nor reference views.